# iTunes smart list - How to specific scenario

Tags: itunes, smart-playlist

I would like to create a smart list with the 25 most played song in the last 7 days. Not the 25 most played of all times, only in the last 7 days!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

How about this *[untested]* ...

[image]

Caveats -

- You need to hit the first  <kbd>+</kbd>   sign to get the second line.
- you may need to play with the 'greater than' parameter.

Comment: i think there was a problem there... link does not show...

Comment: What  ' link'  ..?

Comment: ohh sorry... i read [untested] as unTRUSTED and thought that the link was pointing to a "unfriendly" page...

Comment: ah, sorry... no, links here show like [this](http://www.apple.com) (safe, apple dot com) in blue by default